# How to sort a string alphabetically, with lower case letters coming before their upper case equivalents?

Tags: python, string

Is there a simple way to sort a string in python?

I know you can do

```
string="aCBb"
''.join(sorted(string))
```

And that will sort it into "BCab". But is there any way to get python to sort it into "aBbC"?

Edit: Just to make it clear it is necessary for my application that 'b' goes after 'B', they cant be interchangeable. My original solution, using key=str.lower(), returns them in their original order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to guarantee uppercase gets sorted before lowercase:

```
>>> ''.join(sorted(string, key=lambda s:(s.lower(), s)))
'aBbC'
```

or

```
>>> ''.join(sorted(sorted(string), key=str.lower))
'aBbC'
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the first example in the Python sorting how-to:
http://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sorting.html#key-functions

```
sorted("aCBb", key=str.lower)
```

Using the `str.lower` built in should be faster than a custom lambda.

*edit* Given the constraint that capital letters must come first, gnibbler's answer is correct. If the key returns a tuple, the sort will sort by the first element, then use the second to break ties. In the second case, it sorts first by the case-sensitive representation, then by a case-insensitive version - because `sorted` is stable for values that share the same key this does not undo the first sort. I would be interested in seeing any profiling anyone cares to run regarding which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort it by the lowercase value:

```
"".join(sorted("aCBb", key=lambda x: x.lower())) # => "aBbC"
```

Note that it doesn't guarantee that `"b"` comes after `"B"`, it just happens to work in your example. Equal characters will end up in the same as their original order.